# Determine the maximum depth of a term

Tags: prolog

How can I implement a binary predicate ,computes the depth of the first argument as its second argument.

**Remark:** The depth of variables, numbers, function symbols of arity 0, and predicate symbols of arity 0 is 0.

The depth of a term or an atomic formula is the maximum depth of all subterms or subformulas
plus 1.

```
?-depth((p(X,a(q(Y)),c), X).

X=3
```

My effort: i implemented max_list predicate but i could not develop my code more.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this... You can do it without problem with list but with predicate I'm not sure. But I'm not an expert :-)

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin i used library of use_module(library(lists)) and but i should also use ( i could not) predicates var/1, atomic/1, compound/1, and =../2.

Comment: Note you have a typo (an unclosed parenthesis) in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in one direction I think.

```
depth(A,0):-
 \+compound(A).
depth(A,B):-
 compound(A),
 A =.. [_H|T],
 maplist(depth,T,Depths),
 max_list(Depths,Max),
 B is Max +1.
```

Comment: Why do you remove a line space between defs? I find that harder to read.

Comment: That's the common layout: Only empty lines between clauses of different predicates.

Comment: And if you indent 4 spaces instead of 1 for the clause body, it will be easier to read. :)

Comment: @lurker: or 3 like in the standard.

Comment: @false funny, I always thought all good indent standards evenly divided into the universal tabstop value of 8. :)

Comment: @lurker: To be clear: There is no explicit prescription for 3 spaces, but all example programs in 13211-1 respect this.  (Maybe they are tabs set to a width or 3?). I personally do not like too much indentation, for my eyes have to move too much for them.

Comment: @false, yes, thanks, I understood it to be "by official example". I think *The Craft of Prolog* follows 3 as well? I agree there's such a thing as too much or too little. Either can lead to lowered readability. An indentation level of 1 is just not very distinguishable. Ruby uses 2, which seems to work well. Somewhere between 2 and 4 seems ideal in most cases. In Prolog, you need enough to provide a nice indentation of a `->`/`;` construct, so 3 or 4 seem about right.

Comment: @lurker: Remember 1980's sawtooth indentation?

Comment: @lurker: Craft if Prolog is about 8 - it's all in CMR. But this is on paper.

Comment: @lurker: For completeness: ISO/IEC 9899 (C) has 6, 14882 (C++) has 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple straightforward approach. It treats lists as if they are a flat data structure (even through in reality, they are a deeply nested `./2` structure.

```
depth( T , D ) :- % to compute the depth of an arbitrary term...
  depth(T,0,D)    % - call the worker predicate with the accumulator seeded to zero.
  .

depth( T      , CM , MD ) :- var(T)    , ! , MD is CM+1 . % an unbound term is atomic  : its depth is the current depth + 1 .
depth( T      , CM , MD ) :- atomic(T) , ! , MD is CM+1 . % an atomic term is...atomic : its depth is the current depth + 1 .
depth( [X|Xs] , CD , MD ) :-                              % we're going to treat a list as a flat data structure (it's not really, but conceptually it is)
  findall( D , (member(T,[X|Xs),depth(T,0,D)) , Ds ) ,    % - find the depth of each item in the list
  max(Ds,N) ,                                             % - find the max depth for a list item.
  MD is CD + 1 + N                                        % - the max depth is the current depth + 1 (for the containing list) + the max depth of a list item
  .                                                       %
depth( T , CD , MD ) :-                                   % for other compound terms...
  T \= [_|_] ,                                            % - excluding lists,
  T =.. [_|Args] ,                                        % - decompose it into its functor and a list of arguments
  depth(Args,0,N) ,                                       % - compute the depth of the argument list
  MD is CD + N                                            % - the max depth is the current depth plus the depth of the argument list.
  .                                                       % Easy!

max( [N|Ns] , M ) :- max( Ns , N , M ) . % to compute the maximum value in a list, just call the worker predicate with the accumulator seeded to zero.

max( [] , M , M ) .               % when we hit the end of the list, we know the max depth.
max( [N|Ns] , T , M ) :-          % otherwise,
  ( N > T -> T1 = N ; T1 = T ) ,  % - update the current high water mark
  max(Ns,T1,M)                    % - recurse down.
  .                               % Easy!
```

Answer (score 0):

A list is really just a term, with some syntax sugar that eases most common use. So, my depth/2 definition, a 1-liner given [compound](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compound/1)/1, [aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate/3)/3 and [arg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3)/3 availability, answers like:

```
?- depth(a(a,[1,2,3],c),X).
X = 4.

?- depth(p(X,a(q(Y)),c), X).
X = 3.
```

*edit* I will leave you the pleasure to complete it: fill the dots

```
depth(T, D) :- compound(T) -> aggregate(max(B), P^A^(..., ...), M), D is M+1 ; D = 0.
```

*edit* apparently, no pleasure in filling the dots :)

```
depth(T, D) :-
  compound(T)
  ->  aggregate(max(B+1), P^A^(arg(P, T, A), depth(A, B)), D)
  ;   D = 0.
```

Comment: What is your definition?